# Can't insert data into database with ASP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, webforms

I've been trying to create a simple registration page and connecting it with database, but when I click on the button to register a new user it returns the following message:

```
at MappingDatabase.Connection () [0x00016] in <bea5b5103c9f4cfba42ba460a8c4180f>:0 
at PersonDatabase.Insert (Person p) [0x00002] in <bea5b5103c9f4cfba42ba460a8c4180f>:0
```

Here's the code:

```
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public static class MappingDatabase
{

    public static IDbConnection Connection()
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["databaseConnection"]);
        connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }

    public static IDbCommand Command(string sqlQuery, IDbConnection connection)
    {
        IDbCommand runCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
        runCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;
        return runCommand;
    }
    
    public static IDbDataAdapter Adapter(IDbCommand command)
    {
        IDbDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        return adapter;
    }

    public static IDbDataParameter Parameter(string parameterName, object value)
    {
        return new MySqlParameter(parameterName, value);
    }
}
```

```
public static class PersonDatabase
{

    public static int Insert(Person p)
    {
        try
        {
            IDbConnection dbConnection = MappingDatabase.Connection();
            IDbCommand dbCommand;
            string sql = @"INSERT INTO PER_PERSON VALUES(0, ?name, ?email, ?password);";
            dbCommand = MappingDatabase.Command(sql, dbConnection);
            dbCommand.Parameters.Add(MappingDatabase.Parameter("?name", p.Name));
            dbCommand.Parameters.Add(MappingDatabase.Parameter("?email", p.Email));
            dbCommand.Parameters.Add(MappingDatabase.Parameter("?password", p.Password));
            dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dbConnection.Close();
            dbCommand.Dispose();
            dbConnection.Dispose();
            return 0;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the [repository on GitHub](https://github.com/machado-joao/dotnet-core/tree/main/FirstApp)

It worked before on a computer running Windows 10.
Could it be a problem with the connector file (MySql.Data.dll)? How can I fix that?

Note: I use Linux Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: It looks like you missed a significant portion of the exception details.

Comment: I am actually surprised you get that far running a webforms app on Linux. Your project is small, I highly recommend you re-write it in .NET 6 with MVC or Razor Pages, etc.

Comment: You could set up logging. But seriously, your repo and your question specify .NET Core, but this is not .NET Core. It is .NET Framework and it is old tech. .NET Core and 5 and 6 are actually built to be cross platform.

Comment: Unrelated: `dbCommand.Parameters.Add(MappingDatabase.Parameter("?password", p.Password));` - You are aware that this is a **big** "no no"!?

Comment: I fixed the error. Thank you for your input, @Crowcoder! I am aware that Web Forms is an outdated technology, however, I must use it at college for now.

Comment: Hey, @Fildor! Thank you for your feedback. Could you explain why is that or give me some references? I am a beginner at programming, so I would really appreciate it!

Comment: That is unfortunate. Not only is it old tech, but WebForms hides a lot of how HTTP and javascript work and that is a great disservice to new developers

Comment: Thank you, @Crowcoder! I will do new researches about it!

Comment: _"Could you explain why is that"_ - Persisting Passwords in the db is considered more than unsafe.

Comment: I got it. I will be more careful from now on. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this error by downloading the right connector in the hyperlink below:

[Download Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)